# Слово "отсканированно"

Tags: орфография

Слово "отсканированно" пишется с двумя "н" или одной и почему?

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от контекста. Без него дать однозначный ответ трудно.
Это слово может являться кратким страдательным причастием, и тогда пишется одна буква Н: *отсканировано*. Удвоенное НН пишется в кратких прилагательных (и отглагольных тоже), если удвоенное НН в наличии в полной форме этого прилагательного. Или в наречиях, образованных от прилагательных с удвоенным НН. Вообще-то трудно представить контекст, где это слово было бы отглагольным прилагательным, а тем боле наречием. И тем не менее, для 100-процентной уверенности нужен контекст.